# Magento: Apply navigation filter to a cms page

Tags: php, magento, filter

I created a cms page where I displayed all the products that a have a certain attribute to 1, to do this I customized the file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/list.php

and I used the following code in my page:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_mylist" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/></block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action></block>
</reference>
```

so how can I get the navigation filter to work in my page?

if what I am trying to achieve is not possible, please suggest me another way to do it

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying core file is "no no". You need an extension for this purpose. Fortunately I already wrote one.

https://github.com/openstream/CustomListing

Feel free to as if you will have any questions.

Comment: very nice answer, I will install your extension soon, hope nothing goes wrong so I will not bother you, thank you very match